# Using Tridion2012UI Experience Manager tags with Razor templates

Tags: experience-manager, 2013-sp1, razormediator

I'm trying to use Dominic Cronin's Tridion2012UI functions as detailed at https://github.com/TridionPractice/tridion-practice/wiki/TridionUI2012FunctionsForUseInHtmlTemplates with Razor templates.

I have the DLL compiled and in the GAC and Tridion.ContentManager.config and it's working correctly when I test with DWT templates. I've tried the following markup in Razor templates but am unable to save the template as I'm getting "[whatever you tried] does not exist in the current context" error.

```
@MarkComponentField("Title")

@ExperienceManagerFunctionSource.MarkComponentField("Title")
```

And even the full namespace

```
`@Client.ContentManager.ExperienceManager.ExperienceManagerFunctionSource.MarkComponentField("Title")`
```

Am I just using the incorrect syntax here?

Comment: Some more useful info on XPM markup in Razor can be found here: http://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/4592/54

Answer (score 8):

Have you referenced the assembly (in the GAC) within your `Tridion.ContentManager.config` file?

For example:

```
<razor.mediator cacheTime="60" extractBinaries="true" adminUser="DOMAIN\AdminUser">
    <namespaces>
      <!-- ... -->
    </namespaces>
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="RazorSample.Test, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=60ad7434f03dfcdc" />
    </assemblies>
    <imports>
      <!-- ... -->
    </imports>
  </razor.mediator>
```

If you've already included this then reference then you may want to try restarting the COM+, Tridion Publisher service, and Template Builder (if it’s open). It is always the restarting of the Publisher service that I forget!

NOTE: You can also add your namespace into the `<namespaces>` section (e.g. `<add namespace="Client.ContentManager.ExperienceManager" />`), which will prevent you having to include the `@using XXX` statement at the top of each template.

Comment: Glad you managed to sort it. It's easy to lose hours to this type of issue!

Answer (score 8):

There are two parts to this answer.

The first was pointed out by [Jonathan Williams](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/a/12733/23), I was missing the assembly reference in the razor.mediator configuration

```
<razor.mediator cacheTime="60" extractBinaries="true" adminUser="DOMAIN\AdminUser">
    <namespaces>
      <!-- ... -->
    </namespaces>
    <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Client.ContentManagement.ExperienceManager, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=9b5801bc9141826f" />
    </assemblies>
    <imports>
      <!-- ... -->
    </imports>
  </razor.mediator>
```

The second is that the Tridion2012UIFunctionSource class has an `Initialize` method that you have to call after instantiating the object like so.

```
{
    var ExperienceManager = new Client.ContentManagement.ExperienceManager.ExperienceManagerFunctionSource();
    ExperienceManager.Initialize(TridionHelper.Engine, TridionHelper.Package);
}
```

Then you can go and call your methods like so

`@ExperienceManager.MarkPage("[http://cmeurl]")`